# Error in R: error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'inspect': subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I am trying to run a code in R (see below) But i am getting the error:

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'inspect': subscript out of bounds
```

(I have already installed the libraries but i have deleted from the code to keep it as clean as i can.

the code i am trying to run is:

```
## Go and fetch the result of the previous step. Use the read.transactions to make a transaction object
trans <- read.transactions("TransactionData.csv", format = "single", sep = ",",header=T, cols = c("basket_id", "Category_Merged_Name"))

# There is a useful command just in case you have an almost ready transactional data in a df
# transData <- as (DataFrame_data, "transactions")


## Lets make sure that we have a transaction class item
class(trans)


## Perform some Exploratory Data Analysis 
summary(trans) ## A brief overview of the data.

## Note the distribution of the basket sizes 

## Use the apriori to discover frequent itemsets based on selected support/confidence levels
itemsets <- apriori(trans, parameter = list(support = 0.05, confidence = 0.3, maxlen = 12, minlen = 3))
#view the rules
inspect(sort(itemsets, by="support")[5:10])
# transform results into a data frame
as(itemsets,"data.frame")

##Remove redundant rules 
itemsets <- itemsets[!is.redundant(itemsets)]


# view results with arulesViz
plot(itemsets)
plot(itemsets, engine="interactive")

require(shinythemes)
ruleExplorer(itemsets)
```

I will also add some sample data from the CSV File

(Note that the Category*Merged*_Name contains greek characters and special symbols.

```
"basket_id","Category_Merged_Name"
"1000279697","ΠΟΤΑ_ΜΠΥΡΑ,ΜΗΛΙΤΗΣ_ΜΠΥΡΑ"
"1000279697","ΑΠΟΡΡΥΠΑΝΤΙΚΑ_ΚΑΘΑΡΙΣΤΙΚΑ_ΑΠΟΡΡΥΠΑΝΤ ΠΛΥΝΤΗΡ ΠΙΑΤΩΝ"
"1000279697","ΦΡΟΥΤΑ & ΛΑΧΑΝΙΚΑ_ΦΡΕΣΚΑ ΛΑΧΑΝΙΚΑ_ΚΡΕΜΜΥΔΙΑ - ΣΚΟΡΔΑ ΞΕΡΑ"
"1000279697","ΦΡΟΥΤΑ & ΛΑΧΑΝΙΚΑ_ΦΡΕΣΚΑ ΛΑΧΑΝΙΚΑ_ΠΑΤΑΤΕΣ"
```

What can i do to find out where the problem comes from?